# Writing a unicode file using dbms_xlsprocessor (from ALT16UTF16 Db)

Tags: oracle11g, unicode-string

My Oracle DB is in ALT16UTF16 charcter set.I need to generetae unicode text file which should be imported in another DB in AL32UTF8 encoding. I use for this a PL/sql code which calls the  DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.CLOB2FILE procedure.

In my code process:

- 1st ,I use an NCLOB to store the unicode lines which contains a chinese characters.
- then I call the procedure as: DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.CLOB2FILE(v_file, DIRE, fileName,873)
- where v_file is the NCLOB variable which contains the file and 873 is the Oracle characteset of AL32UTF8

However when I check in the text file I find ¿¿ instead of the chinese caracters, could you help to resolve this or if you can suggest another procedure other than DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.CLOB2FILE which allow writing a large file with the chinese caracters which is extracted from non unicode DB ?

Many Thanks